# How to arrange 3 pictures and change it after swipe

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I need to do something like in attachment. So, there is one picture on the screen and seen 2 neighbouring pictures. In brief, it looks like screen in a music player, where you can swap album covers to change a track. **I need to help how to do it in XML-file**(Recycler view or what?). And it's desirable to give me advice, how after XML realize the swipe in Java-code(DragListener or something else?).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this ain't a free coding-service. We're here to assist you with a specific problem. Please show us your efforts by e.g. pasting your code. Have a look at the help section https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @obscure I don't need help with code, I need to get some advice about instruments I should use

Answer (score 0):

you can set recycler view horizontal like this :-

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Comment: With recycler view the user will be able to scroll more than 1 pic. But I need, that there is be avaliable only 3 pic. (main and 2 neighbours)

Comment: you can set your recycler item left and right margin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager) with [custom Transformer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager#setpagetransformer).

Follow this [nice tutorial](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/14/android-tip-viewpager-with-protruding-children/) for step by step explanation.

Comment: if my answer leads you in right direction. don't forget to accept and upvote so it could be helpful for others too